# How to have a config file outside a CPP dll file

Tags: c++, dll, config

[image: cpp solution explorer]

I have a config.txt file which is in my source folder. I use it to store my baseURL. When i build the dll the config file gets capsulated into one dll.

I am trying to add a config file which will reside outside the dll, so that i can change the base url when needed.

```
using namespace std;


struct Config {
    string baseurl;
};

void loadConfig(Config& config) {
    ifstream fin("config.txt");
    string line;
    while (getline(fin, line)) {
        istringstream sin(line.substr(line.find("=") + 1));
        if (line.find("baseurl") != -1)
            sin >> config.baseurl;
    }
}

#and to access the values

Config config;
loadConfig(config);
```

Also can the dll file access an external config file when placed in the same folder.?

any solutions for this?

Comment: Relative paths in your programs are relative to the [*working directory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of the current process. For programs your run from Visual Studio this is by default (IIRC) the project root directory. You can edit the run-settings to change the working directory, or use an absolute path to the file instead. *Or* you can get the path of the DLL (from inside the DLL) and use that as a base when constructing an absolute path for the file.

Comment: For the latter solution you might want to read about the [`GetModuleHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandlea) and [`GetModuleFilename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea).

Comment: Are you sure you want the DLL to read a config file by itself? It's a more flexible solution to ask the DLL user to supply the base URL, so that the complete application can choose how its configuration is stored.